# How can i remove last element of span tag in menu using jscript?

Tags: php, javascript

i have menu structrue like below

Testimonials | Photo Credits | Privacy Policy | Terms of use|

how do i remove the last pipe (|) symbol using jscript. every pipe(|) within the

```
<li><span> | </span></li>
```

how

Comment: Could you post the real html you're using, instead of a textual demo?

Comment: Why don't you just not put it there in the first place?

Comment: Since you added the PHP tag I assume you've written the server side script as well? In that case I'd do it in PHP.

Comment: If you post the PHP code you use in putting out this menu we can help you in not putting out the pipe for the last element or in removing it on the server side...

Comment: Guessing here: Use [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) instead of string concatenation.

Comment: your question says [jscript, which is the MS version of ECMA script](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/JScript). why is this tagged php or javascript? Please only use the tags you want an answer for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using jQuery?

```
$("li span:last").remove();
```

or like [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) pointed out, just don't place it there in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Since you posted php I'm assuming your code is something like this:

```
$arr = array('Testimonials', 'Photo Credits', 'Privacy Policy', 'Terms of use');

for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    echo '<span> ' . $arr[i] . ' </span><span> | </span>';
}
```

Consider something like this instead:

```
$arr = array('Testimonials', 'Photo Credits', 'Privacy Policy', 'Terms of use');
$notFirst = FALSE;
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    if($notFirst) {
        echo '<span> | </span>';
    }
    $notFirst = TRUE;
    echo '<span>'. $arr[i] . ' </span>';
}
```

Sorry if the syntax is a little off my, I haven't written much php in years

Comment: Even better, add it to an array and use `implode`.